# Permutation group isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

[image]

[image]

I've already proved H is a subgroup as it was very straight forward and easy. I'm certain there is an extremely obvious and easy isomorphism that I am somehow missing. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $\phi:S_{n-1}\to S_n$ as follows: If $\sigma\in S_{n-1}$, let $\phi(\sigma)\in S_n$ be the map $\phi(\sigma)(k)=\sigma(k)$ for $k<n$ and $\phi(\sigma)(n)=n$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense to me. I haven't done algebra in a while so I'm still slowly processing the basics again. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The subgroup $H$ has index $n$ is $S_n$, so must be isomorphic to $S_{n-1}$, as we have seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765486/prove-that-every-positive-integer-n-has-a-unique-expression-of-the-form-2r). But of course, it is much more straightforward to write down an isomorphism.

Comment: Yes I noticed that, which is why I thought the answer would be so obvious, I was just having a lot of troubles figuring out a specific isomorphism. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For any $\sigma\in H$, consider its *restriction* to the set $\bigl\{1,\dots, n-1\bigr\}$.

This restriction of $\sigma$ takes its values in  $\bigl\{1,\dots, n-1\bigr\}$, by definition of $H$, so restricting its codomain to  $\bigl\{1,\dots, n-1\bigr\}$ makes it  a permutation of $S_{n-1}$.