# Prove that all positive integer has a unique representation of the form $2^a.b$ , where $a$ is a non-negative, $b$ is odd.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

In this link [Prove that every positive integer $n$ has a unique expression of the form: $2^{r}m$ where $r\ge 0$ and $m$ is an odd positive integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765486/prove-that-every-positive-integer-n-has-a-unique-expression-of-the-form-2r)  we have a proof without induction (and I understand it). But my teacher wants us to use induction to solve this problem.

How do I go from this: $n = 2^a.b$, to this: $n + 1 = 2^a.b + 1 = 2^c.d$ for some $c$ and $d$?

Comment: Have you learned about strong induction?

Comment: no, I haven't. Do you have a pdf? a link?

Comment: Yeah, you'll need strong induction, not regular induction. In strong induction, you still prove for $1$ then assume the propositions is true for all $n\leq m,$ and prove it is true for $m+1.$ Strong induction really is just regular induction. Starting with your proposition, $P(n),$ we construct a new proposition $Q(n)$ which means "For all $m\leq n,$ $P(n).$ Then strong induction is just proving $Q(n)$ by regular induction. But proving $Q(n)$ for all $n$ all proves $P(n)$ for all $n.$

Answer (score 3):

It is better if the induction is a different one, I mean, suppose that for any number less than $n$, the property holds, then show that the property also holds for $n$. In this case, you can divide it into two cases. First, if $n$ is odd, you are done. Secondly, if $n$ is even. So $n=2k$ for some $k<n$, now apply the property to $k$, which says that $k=2^am$, where $m$ is an odd number, and then $n=2^{a+1}m$ and you get what you want. I hope this proof provides a tool for settling this question using induction.

Comment: As a rule, it would be good to include the term "strong induction."

Comment: Also, this proof requires a few more steps to show uniqueness.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 0):

You can prove by induction. When $n$ is odd, you are done. When $n$ is even, you factor a 2 out, and represent $n/2$ by induction.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).